# Pulsar Reader misses messages that were written when reader was offline

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have a Pulsar reader that reads messages and process them. As and when the messages arrive to a topic the reader receives it. But, say if this reader application was offline for sometime and is back connected to the pulsar cluster, the reader do not read those messages that were written to the Pulsar during the time this reader was offline. However, when the reader is restarted it do not read the old messages that were already consumed. The reader was set with `startMessageId(MessageId.latest)`.

Is this an expected behaviour of the reader or am I missing something? Below is my simple code for a reference.

```
PulsarClient pulsarClient = PulsarClient.builder().serviceUrl(pulsarServiceUrl).build();
Reader<String> reader = pulsarClient.newReader(Schema.STRING).readerName("reader-1").startMessageId(MessageId.latest)
                .topic("persistent://public/default/topic-1").create();
while(true) {
  Message<String> data = reader.readNext(); //blocks if there are no new messages
  System.out.println(data.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the **Reader** interface you have to keep track of the message IDs you are reading from the topic. Because you are using `MessageId.latest`, every time the client connects (for example, after a restart), it positions itself a the end of the topic. If you want to pick up where you left off, then you need to keep track of the last message ID received by the application and use that as `startMessageId`.

If you don't want to keep track of the message IDs, you can get Pulsar to do that for you by using the **Consumer** interface. With a **Consumer** you specify a subscription name which keeps track of your position in the topic. So if a client restarts when using the **Consumer** interface, you will pick up where you left off. See this [page](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-clients/) for more info.

Comment: How do we position the cursor on the last message, and continue reading the stream INCLUDING THE LAST MESSAGE? I can't find a way to do that with the python client.